# Simultaneous dual arm movement

Tags: moveit, robotic-arm, kinematics, ros-humble, move-group

I am attempting to plan and move two arms using moveit2 at the same time. I have setup a move group that contains both arms and am using the c++ move_group_interface to attempt to plan and execute for both arms.

When I try to plan I get the message "No kinematics solver instantiated for group 'both_arms'"  (I have tried to add and remove "both_arms" from the kinematics.yaml but neither seems to work?)

the rest of the planning and execution "finishes successfully" but I imagine thats because no plan is actually being sent to the move_group.

I can successfully plan and move each arm individually but when i attempt to use the combined move group nothing seems to work

I am also able to successfully use the rviz tool to plan and execute for both arms at the same time, its specifically with the c++ api that I am unable to.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

**c++**

```
      bothArmsMoveGroup->setApproximateJointValueTarget(goal_pose, "left_lower_finger_1");
      bothArmsMoveGroup->setApproximateJointValueTarget(goal_pose, "right_lower_finger_1");
      // Plan and execute
      moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;

      bool planning_success =
          (bothArmsMoveGroup->plan(plan) ==
           moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);

      if (planning_success) {
        RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Planning succeeded. Executing movement...");
        bothArmsMoveGroup->execute(plan);
        RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Movement executed successfully.");
      } else {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(LOGGER, "Planning failed for %s",
                     planningGroupName.c_str());
      }
```

**SRDF**

```
<!--This does not replace URDF, and is not an extension of URDF.
    This is a format for representing semantic information about the robot structure.
    A URDF file must exist for this robot as well, where the joints and the links that are referenced are defined
-->
<robot name="avatar-assembly-202303">
    <!--GROUPS: Representation of a set of joints and links. This can be useful for specifying DOF to plan for, defining arms, end effectors, etc-->
    <!--LINKS: When a link is specified, the parent joint of that link (if it exists) is automatically included-->
    <!--JOINTS: When a joint is specified, the child link of that joint (which will always exist) is automatically included-->
    <!--CHAINS: When a chain is specified, all the links along the chain (including endpoints) are included in the group. Additionally, all the joints that are parents to included links are also included. This means that joints along the chain and the parent joint of the base link are included in the group-->
    <!--SUBGROUPS: Groups can also be formed by referencing to already defined group names-->
    <group name="left_arm">
        <joint name="left_shoulder_joint_1"/>
        <joint name="left_shoulder_joint_2"/>
        <joint name="left_forearm_joint"/>
        <joint name="left_elbow_joint"/>
        <joint name="left_wrist_joint"/>
        <joint name="left_hand_joint"/>
    </group>
    <group name="left_gripper">
        <link name="left_finger_1"/>
    </group>
    <group name="right_arm">
        <joint name="right_shoulder_joint_1"/>
        <joint name="right_shoulder_joint_2"/>
        <joint name="right_forearm_joint"/>
        <joint name="right_elbow_joint"/>
        <joint name="right_wrist_joint"/>
        <joint name="right_hand_joint"/>
    </group>
    <group name="right_gripper">
        <link name="right_finger_1"/>
    </group>
    <group name="both_arms">
        <group name="left_arm"/>
        <group name="right_arm"/>
    </group>
    <!--GROUP STATES: Purpose: Define a named state for a particular group, in terms of joint values. This is useful to define states like 'folded arms'-->
    <group_state name="open" group="left_gripper">
        <joint name="left_finger_joint" value="-0.6422"/>
    </group_state>
    <group_state name="closed" group="left_gripper">
        <joint name="left_finger_joint" value="0.3645"/>
    </group_state>
    <group_state name="open" group="right_gripper">
        <joint name="right_finger_joint" value="-0.6422"/>
    </group_state>
    <group_state name="closed" group="right_gripper">
        <joint name="right_finger_joint" value="0.3645"/>
    </group_state>
    <!--END EFFECTOR: Purpose: Represent information about an end effector.-->
    <end_effector name="left_gripper" parent_link="left_lower_finger_1" group="left_gripper" parent_group="left_arm"/>
    <end_effector name="right_gripper" parent_link="right_lower_finger_1" group="right_gripper" parent_group="right_arm"/> 
</robot>
```

**Kinematics.yaml**
(I've tried both having a the separate kinematics for the combined group and keeping is speerate, either way it doesn't seem to work)

```
left_arm:
  kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.0050000000000000001
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.0050000000000000001
right_arm:
  kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.0050000000000000001
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.0050000000000000001
both_arms:
  kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_plugin/KDLKinematicsPlugin
  kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.0050000000000000001
  kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.0050000000000000001
```

**Launch File**

```
import os
import yaml
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.substitutions import (
    Command,
    FindExecutable,
    LaunchConfiguration,
    PathJoinSubstitution,
)
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument



def load_file(package_name, file_path):
    package_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
    absolute_file_path = os.path.join(package_path, file_path)

    try:
        with open(absolute_file_path, "r") as file:
            return file.read()
    except EnvironmentError:  # parent of IOError, OSError *and* WindowsError where available
        return None


def load_yaml(package_name, file_path):
    package_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
    absolute_file_path = os.path.join(package_path, file_path)

    try:
        with open(absolute_file_path, "r") as file:
            return yaml.safe_load(file)
    except EnvironmentError:  # parent of IOError, OSError *and* WindowsError where available
        return None


def generate_launch_description():

    robot_description_semantic_config = load_file(
        "Moveit2", "config/avatar-assembly-202303.srdf"
    )
    robot_description_semantic = {
        "robot_description_semantic": robot_description_semantic_config
    }
    
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [
                    FindPackageShare("avatar"),
                    "urdf",
                    "avatar.xacro",
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    kinematics_yaml = load_yaml(
        "Moveit2", "config/kinematics.yaml"
    )

    planning_plugin = {"planning_plugin": "chomp_interface/CHOMPPlanner"}
    
    sim_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'sim_mode',
        default_value='false', 
        description='Launch in sim_mode if true'
    )
    

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            sim_arg,
            Node(
                package="avatar",
                executable="planner_bridge_plugin",
                parameters=[
                    robot_description,
                    robot_description_semantic,
                    kinematics_yaml,
                    planning_plugin,
                    {"use_sim_time": LaunchConfiguration('sim_mode')},
                ],
            )
        ]
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after trial and error and looking around for a while online I seems to have found a solution, from what I understand multi chain planning is possible but not multi chain kinematics solving. essentially this means that you need to solve the kinematics of each move group independently (moveit2 does not support multi chain kinematic solver? this doesnt seem to be specified anywhere nor mentioned in the documents) and then pass the solved joint states to the combined move group planner.

Essentially:

1. Use individual move_groups to calculate desired angles based on pose
2. extract the joint angles
3. combine the joint angles as expected by the dual arm group (this isn't documented I had to trial and error)
4. then plan the movements with the dual arm group using the combined joint angles

Here is my code:

````
  geometry_msgs::msg::Pose rightGoalPose = msg->poses.back();
  geometry_msgs::msg::Pose leftGoalPose = msg->poses.front();

    // Calculate Kinematics for each arm individually using separate move_groups
    leftArmMoveGroup->setJointValueTarget(leftGoalPose);
    rightArmMoveGroup->setJointValueTarget(rightGoalPose);

    std::vector<double> leftJointValue;
    std::vector<double> rightJointValue;


    leftArmMoveGroup->getJointValueTarget(leftJointValue);
    rightArmMoveGroup->getJointValueTarget(rightJointValue);

    std::vector<double> bothJointsSend;

    bothJointsSend.insert(bothJointsSend.end(), rightJointValue.begin(),
                          rightJointValue.end());
    bothJointsSend.insert(bothJointsSend.end(), leftJointValue.begin(),
                          leftJointValue.end());

    auto successCheck = bothArmsMoveGroup->setJointValueTarget(bothJointsSend);

    std::vector<double> bothJointValue;
    bothArmsMoveGroup->getJointValueTarget(bothJointValue);


    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;
    bool planning_success =
        (bothArmsMoveGroup->plan(plan) ==
         moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);

    if (planning_success) {
      RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Planning succeeded. Executing movement...");
      bothArmsMoveGroup->execute(plan);
      // rightArmMoveGroup->execute(planRight);
      RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER, "Movement executed successfully.");
    } else {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(LOGGER, "Planning failed for both arms");
    }

```
````

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, move_group can plan for only 1 chain at a time. So in theory you could plan each arm's path separately. If they are close together, collision with the other arm seems like it'll be a potential issue. Maybe well-chosen constraints can help with that.

I'd expect that executing a merged trajectory should then be straightforward.

Comment: See my answer, but seems like it was the kinematic solving that cannot be done with combined group? I appreciate the answer nonetheless.